# Fetch all the entries/word/line after a specfic word in Grafana using regex

Tags: regex, grafana

I am new to regex and need some help in fetching all the entries after a specific word. I am working on Grafana panels and using option "Filter data by values" under edit option

Let the specific word be `"sample_word"` post which I want to fetch everything no matter what.

My sample string is below

`700 <10> 2022-11-21T05:00:09 sample_word="abc.net"] 2022-11-21T05:00:09 | api.call | line 100 | INFO | [123456]`

I tried below which but couldn't figure out the solution

`/.+?(?=sample_word)/g`

Comment: Do you want to fetch all content _before_ `sample_word` or after it?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for replying, I would require all the content after the sample_word please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a fixed width positive lookbehind here:

```
(?<=\bsample_word).*
```

This would match all content in the log line after `sample_word`.  Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSSvg5/1).